# newbie to js. how do i ask user for input with function

Tags: javascript

Improved hello
Complete the following program so that it asks the user for his first and last names, then show the result of the sayHello() function.

```
// Say hello to the user
function sayHello(firstName, lastName) {
  const message = `Hello, ${firstName} ${lastName}!`;
  return message;
}

// TODO: ask user for first and last name
// TODO: call sayHello() and show its result
```

Comment: If you are this new to js, then stackoverflow is the wrong place. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/5734311)

Comment: `console.log(sayHellow('Joe', 'Schmoe')` or `document.getElementById('htmlDivElementIdHere').innerHTML = sayHellow('Joe', 'Schmoe')`.

Comment: use either the prompt function or define html with input field and catch the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
function askForName() {
  var person = prompt("Please enter your first and last name:");
  if (person !== null) {
    var firstName = person.split(' ')[0]; 
    var lastName = person.split(' ')[1];
    console.log(sayHello(firstName, lastName));
  }
}

function sayHello(firstName, lastName) {
  const message = `Hello, ${firstName} ${lastName}!`;
  return message;
}

askForName();
```

The result will be logged to your console.

Comment: @tintin42 Have you called `myFunction`?

Comment: @Xufox yes i have but its showing up as error for some reason

Comment: @tintin42 What error? How do you display the result of `sayHello`?

Comment: @tintin42 Have you _replaced_ your existing code with this code? Why would you do that?

Comment: @Xufox what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Although I've omitted your template literals from my answer *(for compatibility reasons)*. This should show you some basic JavaScript.

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, htm, M, I, S, Q, old = onload; // for use on other loads
onload = function(){
if(old)old(); // change old var name if using technique on other pages
doc = document; bod = doc.body; htm = doc.documentElement;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
S = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
I('f').onsubmit = function(){
  return false;
}
var first = I('first'), last = I('last'), show = I('show'), out = I('out');
show.onclick = function(){
  out.innerHTML = first.value+' '+last.value; first.value = last.value = '';
}
}
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:940px; background:#ccc; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <form id='f' name='f'>
      <input id='first' name='first' type='text' placeholder='First Name' />
      <input id='last' name='last' type='text' class='empty' placeholder='Last Name' />
      <input id='show' name='show' type='button' value='Display Input' />
    </form>
    <div id='out'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```